# making a GET request to a webservice from the playframework 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, webrequest

I'm trying to call a webservice from the play framework, and I think I'm doing it wrong. I have an example call to http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=eDKGlpcBQN&query=52.6%2C-4.4&output=xml

A snippet from what I'm trying from the playframework is the following:

```
val response = WS.url("http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=eDKGlpcBQN&query=52.6%2C-4.4&output=xml").get.get()
val body = response.getBody
```

When I call this, the body consists of "useraccount does not exist". When I just put this url in a browser, I get the response I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Yeah strange, it even works when using `curl`.

Comment: what does the 'val' here mean, is that a play class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason, I was getting WS from the wrong import. When I fixed the imports to `import play.api.libs.ws.WS`, it worked. I'm still amazed it worked halfway with the wrong import

Comment: The play framework documentation mentions the other import and that does not work. Not sure why. Thankfully someone found out the reason. Had a tough time figuring this one out.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about "useraccount does not exist" but this seems to work:

```
  val promise = WS.url("http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=eDKGlpcBQN&query=52.6%2C-4.4&output=xml").get()
  val body = promise.value.get.body
```

Edit: Removed the space.

Also make sure your editor is not inserting a `\n` or `\r` after `?`

Comment: `promise.value` isn't working for me. Is that part of play2.0? Also, is that space supposed to be there after the ?

Comment: for promise.value, see [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I just solved this problem while trying to do the same thing - getting the same results.

GET variables must be passed with WS.url("http://...").setQueryParameter(key, value)

Example:

```
val promise = WS.url("http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx").setQueryParameter("uac", "eDKGlpcBQN").setQueryParameter("query", "52.6%2C-4.4").setQueryParameter("output", "xml").get()
```

Annoying, but a relatively simple fix.